# CSS Not Recognized

Tags: html, css, indexing, stylesheet

So I am trying to make my first mobile-first website and my first problem is that the index.html file doesn't recognize my style.css file to stylize all the different div tags. The style.css file is located in a css folder, along with the normalization.css file. Here is my code for the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Put on a Show, Monkey-Boy</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/normalization.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
```

Were the CSS working properly, there would be a background color, the divs would have their own individual colors and sizes, fonts would be stylized in Nunito and Lato respectively, and positions of block text would be different. I am using the latest version of Chrome.

I looked at the other threads relating to this topic, but none seemed exactly the same as the problem that I am having.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance,

Todd

Comment: simple fiddle would be better.

Comment: @can you check in resources whether the css file is loaded or not? If it is not, share the folder structure, if it is then share the css

Comment: Try removing the first `/` inside your `href` attributes.

Comment: A link would be bette...looks like a path issue.

Comment: try to add ".." before "/" if its relatively placed or remove "/" if its placed inside css folder

Comment: Thank you so for replying, everybody! I tried taking the "/" away inside my href attribute but unfortunately had no luck. I feel like this is a path issue too, although when I download similar files off of teamtreehouse.com, I usually have no problems with getting the css to work instantly.

Comment: Have you tried **`<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`**

Comment: Yep, that didn't work either. :-/ (Sigh) Is there a public hosting website where I can publicly show these files to you? I would use my EnglishTeacherTodd.com website to show off these files, but I'm a little worried about screwing things up even more.

Comment: A link would be the best option.

Comment: Is your file named style.css or styles.css ?

Comment: Alright, I've put the file on my EnglishTeacherTodd.com website: EnglishTeacherTodd.com/index222.html. I'm still having the same problem. I changed the css file to style2.css so that the index222 would link to style2.css. Still, isn't recognizing the css.

Comment: Also, here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/toddsqui/6pxn0oro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget a closing curly bracket after the *-selector.

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pxn0oro/2/

Also you should put your normalization.css before the style.css , so you don't overwrite your created styles.

Comment: This is what fixed my problem!! Hahaha!

Thank you so much, Chris! Adding that final bracket made all the difference! I can't believe it!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove `/` on your link.

Before:

```
<head>

    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/normalization.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

After:

```
<head>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/normalization.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Tarjo! Thanks so much for the reply! I did what you said, but oddly enough, the CSS is still not recognized! I have no idea what on Earth is the problem! This never happens when I use other people's files. Haha.

Comment: maybe you could use jsfiddle to demo your problem. 
so that the problem can be known. 
have you tried in the local host or on your server?

Answer (score 0):

After how many years of development, you wouldn't believe how often I find myself scratching my head with this exact problem.

Firstly, make sure the *css* folder is in the root directory of your site. This is where the leading slash (*/*) is pointing to. Alternatively, if you remove this as suggested, then it becomes a relative path. Relative to the directory you're in. So in that case, the *css* folder should be in the same directory as the your *index.html* file. (Note, that depending on how you have your webserver setup, what you see as the root directory, may not be the actual root directory. In which case a relative path can be useful).

Also, make sure your css is correct, no typos in class names or anything like that. I'll usually apply something very simple that I know will work, such as a background color to the *body* element. For example:

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Use a code editor with syntax highlighting to help you address any errors both in your CSS, and in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much user110149! I figured out the problem. The directories were all in their proper place, but I left out a closing-bracket on one of the vendor prefixes. I can't believe doing that rendered my css completely irrelevant. 

Anyway, thank you so much for the detailed response, and reassuring me that I'm not losing my mind and becoming a really crappy coder. I appreciate it! ;)